# Infinite Scroll + Advanced Ajax Page Loader - new content links no longer use ajax | Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I know very little about AJAX, jQuery and reload codes, so keep that in mind.

So, my WordPress site uses the plugins "Infinite Scroll" and "Advanced Ajax Page Loader."

What happens is, upon initial load of my site, the 10 posts that display by default all function properly (opening in-line via Ajax [AAPL] when clicked).

Now, when I utilize the Infinite Scroll function by scrolling down my page to reveal the next 10 posts, the link titles of the posts will no longer open in-line via AJAX.

when new content is loaded, the Advanced Ajax Page Loader plugin will not work for any of the newly revealed content/links.

What can I do to make these newly called links utilize my AAPL Ajax plugin. Do I need some sort of Reload Code or jQuery script?

Comment: http://bossflow.com for an example of what I described above

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refresh AAPL. To do this go to the "Infinite Scroll" plugin options page, locate the Callback textarea and paste `AAPL_loadPageInit("");`